# Syntax highlighting for Javascript/PHP file in PHPStorm weird

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Since recently PHPStorm doesn't do the highlighting in my large folders anymore. I tried this :

- removing ~./WebIde7.0
- delete all .idea folders
- complete 're-installing' PHPStorm
- flipping PowerSave mode in the inspection level up and down
- using an older PHPStorm version

but no success. I also noticed that PHPStorm got pretty dumb with PHP files; in some files its marking function calls in red whilst there is no problem at all.

I've got the most recent & expensive hardware you can get right now on the market. It shouldn't be a problem as with low-budget machines.

I admit my project folders did grow to a few thousands of files but I simply can't mark them as excluded; I tried this too but no, PHPStorm behaves still dumb and broken.

Setup : Ubuntu - 12 ( I tried Gnome & Ubuntu -2D) | x64 | Oracle-Java-1.7 with 4GB RAM for PHPStorm 1.7.

I also noticed such problems with recent Webstorm versions, its getting dumber and dumber and I am really considering to step off Jetbrains...

Any ideas, except excluding folders ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an example of such file. IDE will not run any analysis (and as result of it syntax highlighting) if file is above 2.5MB (or so) in size.

Comment: download the entire dojo repos and place them together with a few hundred of PHP files to reproduce this.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't remove ~./WebIde7.0 for real, after this removal it seems back working normal. However, this sucks because I lost all settings. Not really the purpose of an IDE...

Comment: If you have backup you can restore most of the config files. P.S. If I would be removing something from WebIde folder .. I would remove `system` subfolder (indexes/caches/etc) and maybe plugins. Simple deleting without backing it up first and then complaining about it does not help here at all as it's not possible to investigate what was wrong now.